# Show option only when there are no results

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to hardcode in an option to an `ng-options` select list when the scope it is pulling from has no answers. I was able to achieve this in another scenario by doing something like that:

```
ng-show="!$scope.length"
```

However, it does not seem to be working inside the select list itself. Perhaps it's something with how Angular does `ng-options`? Here is my attempt:

```
<select ng-model="myModel" ng-options="option.title for option in optionsList">
    <option ng-show="!optionsList.length">There are no prompts for this lesson.</option>
</select>
```

I have hardcoded an option inside of the select with the same logic, but it does not seem to want to work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ng-options` will over-write that option.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to create a filter that inserts the default option if empty...

```
.filter('defaultOptionIfEmpty', function () {
    return function (items, defaultItem) {
        return items.length ? items : [defaultItem];
    }
});
```

Use it like this...

```
<select ng-model="foo" ng-options="item.value for item in items | defaultOptionIfEmpty : {id: 0, value: 'There are no prompts for this lesson.'}">
</select>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqcbybtn/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data for options is "dataBlocksHere.currentData.selections", you need to pre-process this block to check if there is anything in it, and insert the appropriate content into it.
So before you assign the item to scope, process the results in your javascript.

```
 if(!dataBlocksHere.currentData.selections){
      // insert item into selections, something like
      dataBlocksHere.currentData.selections['data'] = {id: 0, data: "There are no prompts for this lesson."};

 }
```